# Nginx embedded variables $arg_timestamp seems to be missing

Tags: nginx

I've just hit something strange and can't explain or even reproduce on other server - embedded variable $arg_timestamp missing for some reason.

Server config:

```
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 80;

  location /{
    add_header X-foo $args;
    add_header X-bar $arg_timestamp;
    add_header X-bar $arg_timestam;
    return 204;
  }
}
```

and some tests

```
ogryzek% curl -D - -s 'http://fqdn/?timestamp=3' 
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 22:47:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
X-foo: timestamp=3

ogryzek% curl -D - -s 'http://fqdn/?timestam=3'
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 22:47:56 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
X-foo: timestam=3
X-bar: 3
```

Comment: The [Nginx change log](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES) doesn't list any Nginx 1.6 versions. If there was a 1.6 it would be three years old. Can you try updating to 1.13?

Comment: Yes I can, but this is the newest nginx in Jessie and such behavior is uncommon even for that version. I have bunch of servers with that system/nginx and only one have problem. Of course the configurations have been compare.

Answer (score 0):

I have found cause of the problem - [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

One of other vhost have

```
if ($args ~* "(.*)timestamp=([0-9]{7})([0-9]{3})($|\&.*)" ) {
  set $arg_timestamp $2000;
}
```